# Method not found - findOrCreateWhere - gorm

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have created a Role class that contains only one variable authority:

```
class Role {
    String authority
}
```

Now when I try to save new values in BootStrap.groovy (grails app) I am doing this:

```
def adminRole = Role.findOrCreateWhere(authority: "ROLE_ADMIN");
```

When I am running this I am getting the following exception:

```
2012-01-29 23:35:03,067 [Thread-9] ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.rango.auth.Role.findOrCreateWhere() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findOrCreateWhere(java.util.Map), findOrSaveWhere(java.util.Map)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.rango.auth.Role.findOrCreateWhere() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findOrCreateWhere(java.util.Map), findOrSaveWhere(java.util.Map)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:290)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:283)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:259)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.rango.auth.Role.findOrCreateWhere() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findOrCreateWhere(java.util.Map), findOrSaveWhere(java.util.Map)
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:16)
    ... 8 more
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Was your `Role` class created by Spring Security?  If not, was it created in the `grails-app/domain` subfolder?  It's only going to have domain class features if it's in that folder.  Have you tried running `grails clean` first?

Answer (score -1):

try this: def adminRole = Role.findOrCreateWhere([authority: "ROLE_ADMIN"]);

Comment: That's the exact same thing in Groovy.  `method(foo: bar)` is just syntactic sugar for passing a map in as the first argument.